# PostSharp, how to inject a value besides using the method interface?

Tags: postsharp, aop

Is there anyway to inject a value into a method besides modifying/overriding one of the arguments in the interface?  for example:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyTestAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
     public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
     {
         String someValue = "123";
     }
}

public class MyClass
{
     [MyTest]
     public void doSomething()
     {
        String otherValue = "456" + someValue;
     }

}
```

Where `someValue` is declared in the aspect, but accessible within the doSomething method WITHOUT passing it in via the method interface. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide an example of scenario where such functionality will be useful?

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one possible solution: it's to combine *aspect-oriented approach* with *dependency injection*. *Unfortunately this approach is limited to specific kind of scenarios* (check last section of answer).

### InjectedAspect advice

First, define `someValue` to be *optional dependency* of class containing target method. You could do this by extracting interface out of class with this *dependency*

```
public interface IServiceWithDependency
{
    int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Second, make target class to implement this interface

```
public class MyClass : IServiceWithDependency
{
    // dependency
    public int SomeValue { get; set; } 

    // aspect
    [InjectedAspect] 
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        string otherValue = "456" + SomeValue;
    }
}
```

Now we need aspect to inject this dependency

```
[Serializable]
public class InjectedAspectAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Instance is IServiceWithDependency)
        {
            // inject actual value of dependency
            (args.Instance as IServiceWithDependency).SomeValue = 123;
        }

        args.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Optionally you could add compile-time validation to make sure that this aspect applied only to classes that implement `IServiceWithDependency`

```
  [Serializable]
        public class InjectedAspectAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
        {
            public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
            {
                var result = true;
                var methodInfo = method as MethodInfo;

                if (!typeof(IServiceWithDependency).IsAssignableFrom(method.DeclaringType))
            {
                Message.Write(methodInfo, SeverityType.Error, "999", string.Format("Only class derived from IServiceWithDependencyallowed, {0} not implements IServiceWithDependency", method.DeclaringType));

                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            /* … */
        }
    }
```

Full sample is available [here](https://gist.github.com/4468274)

### When to apply and what kind of scenarios are this aspect

Initial idea came from transaction managment aspect, when there is no ambient `TransactionScope`, instead transaction object is injected into every class which need to handle transaction. Some important details:

- This aspect is not only not thread-safe, but if you call several methods decorated with this aspect on one instance of class you could possibly override previously injected value
- Previous limitation is not a problem, when you have Controller-like class in MVC application, and only one method will be called per instance of class
- Also this is some kind of code smell global variable in scope of one class, so this approach should be applied carefuly only if it's really helps